# Identify this insect - beetle (?)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify this insect - genus, species and anything interesting about it. (Species of beetle?)

Old link - please vote to un-delete it https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/can-you-identify-these-insects?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's a red rhinoceros beetle. Although, "red rhinoceros beetle" is not the correct name. I'm simply observing that it is red, and that it is a rhinoceros beetle. So, according to wikipedia: suborder [Dynastinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynastinae). Do an image search for "red rhinoceros beetle" and you'll stuff that looks quite similar. Searching google for that specific image show's that it is a 3d printed model. The list of bugs in list of 3d printed models includes something called "Rozenkever". Which is remarkably similar to "Red Beetle" in German.

*Golofa porteri* perhaps

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/animals/insect/meikever) is a gallery of this 3d printed beetle. Also, the artist of that beetle is from Belgium, so the translation makes sense.

Comment: Is there any way we can get this down to the species identification? the missing link from above, long story short, the artist sent these files to me without proper naming for an entomology app I'm developing. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/can-you-identify-these-insects?

Comment: golofa porteri seems likely then.

Comment: @Charles Translation makes no sense at all. Rozenkever is Dutch, not German and means "rose beetle", not "red beetle". Your link shows an image, with the name "Meikever", meaning "May beetle". However, this is not a meikever Melolontha melolontha.